# How can I pass xml data from the controller to the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    XElement xml = 
         new XElement("persoanldetails", from i in dbContext.Personaldetails
                                                   where i.ID == 1 select i);
    return View(xml);
}
```

I have created an `XElement` in the controller. It converts my data in the database to xml. Now I want to use this xml object to load the grid in dhtmlx.

How can I retrieve the xml object in the view?

Comment: Would you not just serialise an object and return that to the view.  Then you can do what you like with it?

Comment: Seems similar to this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/412331/passing-a-xml-parsed-list-from-a-controller-to-a-view-in-asp-net-mvc Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MvcContrib has an `XmlResult`

http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/documentation